# Loading a state into a div from anywhere with angularjs and ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="messengerPane">
</div>
```

It will be on every state / view of the app, I need to load different views into it with parameters on click:

ex:

```
<a>Message</a>
```

That ui-sref opens the messenger window for the entire view, I only want to load that state into the div, I can't do a nested state because it has to be accessible from any state.

Note that I already have another `<div ui-view></div>` elsewhere

Here is a plnkr showing what I am trying to do:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qbg8E2

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the view inside that div

```
<div class="messengerPane">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to load other views in addition to this one

Comment: do you want to load multiple views in same page?

Comment: @Jordash - the ui-view directive will just load in whatever template is associate with the state you call whether it be using ui-sref of $state.go() calls. Before this answer was posted how were you using ui-view in the first place?

Comment: Yeah multiple views on the same page, but from within any state.

Comment: i didn't get your point. why do you need that.. kindly explain about outer div, and if it is just this div then it makes no sense to waste a lot of your and our time...

Comment: I need to load the view into the messengerpane without a route change, similar to how Facebook pops up their messenger window

Comment: I simply put that ui-view inside that div and now your state/ page will be shown inside that div. for your confirmation, I am going to make background color grey

Comment: So for example if I am in State 2 I need to load the messenger.html template into the .messengerPane class (passing through any parameter) while still staying in state 2 ditto for state 1

Comment: How do I see it? Is there a link?

Comment: yeah, state 2 contains a link that redirects to messenger, I also added a state for messenger

Comment: I think you have to share the link

Comment: It's not working properly, when I am in state 2 it needs to stay in state 2 and add the messenger.html file into the .messengerPane and same with state1, this changes out of state2 into the messenger state

Comment: @Jordash - I have the similar requirement - did you find a workaround?